# Packer doesn't reboot AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, packer

I'm building an AMI with Hashicorp Packer and this are one of the steps:

```
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "script": "scripts/apt.sh"
    },
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "inline": ["sudo reboot"],
      "inline_shebang": "/bin/bash -e",
      "expect_disconnect": true
    },
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "script": "scripts/sysctl.sh",
      "pause_before": "10s"
    },
```

and here the result:

```
Provisioning with shell script: scripts/apt.sh
==> amazon-ebs: Provisioning with shell script: /tmp/packer-shell376239929
==> amazon-ebs: Pausing 10s before the next provisioner...
==> amazon-ebs: Provisioning with shell script: scripts/sysctl.sh
    amazon-ebs: net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0
    amazon-ebs: net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects = 0
    amazon-ebs: net.ipv4.conf.default.send_redirects = 0
```

It is pretty visible that Packer doesn't somehow interpret the reboot command but immediately run the next command even though I put there the pause attribute. It waits for that 10sec but then no reboot happens.

```
    amazon-ebs: + sudo reboot now
2018/01/31 20:54:34 ui:     amazon-ebs: + sudo reboot now
2018/01/31 20:54:34 packer: 2018/01/31 20:54:34 Remote command exited without exit status or exit signal.
2018/01/31 20:54:34 packer: 2018/01/31 20:54:34 [INFO] RPC endpoint: Communicator ended with: 2300218
2018/01/31 20:54:34 [INFO] 0 bytes written for 'stdout'
2018/01/31 20:54:34 [INFO] 18 bytes written for 'stderr'
2018/01/31 20:54:34 [INFO] RPC client: Communicator ended with: 2300218
2018/01/31 20:54:34 [INFO] RPC endpoint: Communicator ended with: 2300218
2018/01/31 20:54:34 packer: 2018/01/31 20:54:34 [INFO] 0 bytes written for 'stdout'
2018/01/31 20:54:34 packer: 2018/01/31 20:54:34 [INFO] 18 bytes written for 'stderr'
2018/01/31 20:54:34 packer: 2018/01/31 20:54:34 [INFO] RPC client: Communicator ended with: 2300218
2018/01/31 20:54:34 packer: 2018/01/31 20:54:34 opening new ssh session
2018/01/31 20:54:34 packer: 2018/01/31 20:54:34 ssh session open error: 'EOF', attempting reconnect
2018/01/31 20:54:34 packer: 2018/01/31 20:54:34 reconnecting to TCP connection for SSH
2018/01/31 20:54:34 packer: 2018/01/31 20:54:34 handshaking with SSH
2018/01/31 20:54:34 packer: 2018/01/31 20:54:34 handshake complete!
2018/01/31 20:54:34 packer: 2018/01/31 20:54:34 [INFO] no local agent socket, will not connect agent
2018/01/31 20:54:35 packer: 2018/01/31 20:54:35 starting remote command: rm -f /tmp/script_5069.sh
2018/01/31 20:54:35 packer: 2018/01/31 20:54:35 [INFO] RPC endpoint: Communicator ended with: 0
2018/01/31 20:54:35 [INFO] RPC client: Communicator ended with: 0
2018/01/31 20:54:35 [INFO] RPC endpoint: Communicator ended with: 0
2018/01/31 20:54:35 packer: 2018/01/31 20:54:35 [INFO] RPC client: Communicator ended with: 0
2018/01/31 20:54:35 [INFO] (telemetry) ending shell
2018/01/31 20:54:35 [INFO] (telemetry) Starting provisioner file
2018/01/31 20:54:35 ui: ==> amazon-ebs: Pausing 10s before the next provisioner...
==> amazon-ebs: Pausing 10s before the next provisioner...
2018/01/31 20:55:05 ui: ==> amazon-ebs: Uploading conf => /tmp
==> amazon-ebs: Uploading conf => /tmp
2018/01/31 20:55:05 packer: 2018/01/31 20:55:05 Upload dir 'conf' to '/tmp'
2018/01/31 20:55:05 packer: 2018/01/31 20:55:05 opening new ssh session
2018/01/31 20:55:32 packer: 2018/01/31 20:55:32 ssh session open error: 'ssh: unexpected packet in response to channel open: <nil>', attempting reconnect
2018/01/31 20:55:32 packer: 2018/01/31 20:55:32 reconnecting to TCP connection for SSH
2018/01/31 20:55:32 packer: 2018/01/31 20:55:32 reconnection error: dial tcp 10.211.207.8:22: getsockopt: connection refused
2018/01/31 20:55:32 [INFO] (telemetry) ending file
2018/01/31 20:55:32 [INFO] (telemetry) found error: dial tcp 10.211.207.8:22: getsockopt: connection refused
==> amazon-ebs: Terminating the source AWS instance...
```

Comment: What's the output if you add debug  to bash `-x` and run with `PACKER_LOG=1 packer build template.json`?

Comment: @RickardvonEssen as you might see the reboot command is executed and immediately the SSH is again up and in the next command it fails

Comment: Retrying after several attempts, it works. Very flaky anyway

Comment: Everything looks correct in the last log. Maybe you should increase the `pause_before` if you have problems that it reconnects before the instance has shutdown ssh.

Comment: Oh gotcha I got it what it happened. `sudo reboot now` is executed. However the ssh agent is still active so Packer reconnect immediately to it. At the next command then the ssh agent has been killed hence the ssh reconnection failure explained. So in this case the solution is to increase the `pause_before` properties.

Comment: Sounds like the right solution.